# Convert decimal values in 1D array to 2D array with bit values, transpose the 2D bit array and convert to 1D decimal array again

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

My problem is part of a larger communication algorithm I'm trying to implement. The point is to generate packets from messages, to send over the network. You fetch a batch of messages (decimal values), and form the packets from the bits from each message that are in the same column. The following figure illustrates this.

[Packet formation from messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr8Gj.png)

My problem is the 'transpose' operation. How I'm trying to approach this is by transposing the bits of this 1D decimal value array of messages. Maximum decimal value of each message is 255, so 8 bits in length each.

I want to convert all decimal values to bits in a 2D array, where each column is a bit from the decimal value in that row. Finally I want to convert this 2D bit array to a 1D array with decimal values again.

Example:

1. Input is a decimal 1D array

   ```
   decimal[16] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
   ```
2. Convert this 1D array to a 2D array representing the bits

   ```
   bits[16][8] = { 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
                   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
                   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
                        ....         
                   0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 };
   ```
3. Transpose this bit array

   ```
   bits2[8][16] = {
         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
         0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
         0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
         0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 };
   ```
4. Convert it back to a decimal value 1D array

   ```
   result[8] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 3855, 13107, 21845}
   ```

The code I have so far:

```
#define n 8     // COLUMNS
#define m 16    // ROWS

int data[m];
int result[n];
int i,j;
int counter = 0;

memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));
memset(result, 0, sizeof(result));

for ( i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
  data[i] = counter;
  ++counter;
}

int a[m][n], b[n][m], x;

// Convert decimal array to 2D bit array
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
        x = data[i];
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
                 a[i][j] = (x & 0x8000) >> 8;
                 x <<= 1;
        }
}

// Transpose bit array
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
         for(j=0; j<n; j++)
         {
                  b[j][i] = a[i][j];
         }
}

// Convert back to decimal
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
         for(j=0; j<m; j++)
         {
                  if (b[i][j] == 1) result[i] = result[i] * 2 + 1;
                  else if (b[i][j] == 0) result[i] *= 2;
         }
}
```

I hope my explanation is clear! If not, I'll gladly explain some more. I've searched endlessly for ways to do this but I'm still not getting up with a solid solution.

PS: Apologies for the bad code formatting of the arrays, didn't find a proper way to visualize it without linking an image.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't print the binary values without converting it to the obscure [16][8] int matrix? It's 128 bytes waste of space (512 if `int`) and likely slower to address than the original data too, since you have to calculate offsets over and over.

Comment: This is no valid C code. Learn [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: You've explained what you want you're trying to do.  You've shown some code.   You've not explained what problems you're having.  The disassembly and reassembly is going to be fairly messy more or less regardless of how you do it, I think.  You should package this as a function which is passed the input and output arrays.  There's probably no need to memset either array; they'll be initialized properly if your code is working correctly.  Your test code should include a `main` program which should be quite short — it should print the input data, call the function, and print the result.

Comment: Incidentally, you should be able to extract the bits into the right position in the transposed array; you then only have to reassemble the data from that.  At worst.

Comment: @Lundin I think you're proposing the same as Jonathan Leffler, and I'll give it a go. Seems far more efficient indeed. Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the info and the notes, it's only my first question on here so I'm still learning the ropes :) I think you're saying the same as Lundin so I'll give that a go :)

Comment: @Olaf my apologies, it's only my first question, but I'm trying to improve :) thanks for the links provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should provide the desired output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define n 8     // COLUMNS
#define m 16    // ROWS
int main(void)
{
    int data[m];
    int result[n];
    int i, j;
    int counter = 0;

    memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));
    memset(result, 0, sizeof(result));

    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)   // print initial data
    {
        data[i] = counter;
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
        ++counter;
    }
    putchar('\n');
    char a[m][n], b[n][m];
    int x;

    // Convert decimal array to 2D bit array
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        x = data[i];
        for (j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            a[i][j] = x & 1;
            x >>= 1;
        }
    }

    // Transpose bit array
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            b[j][i] = a[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Convert back to decimal
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (b[i][j] == 1)
                result[i] = result[i] * 2 + 1;
            else if (b[i][j] == 0)
                result[i] *= 2;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)      // print result
    {
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

What you were doing wrong was the conversion to the 2d bit array , it was all filled with 0's.
You were doing (x&0x8000) >> 8; 
0x8000 = 1000 0000 0000 0000 (grouped in nibbles to see clearly)
so (x&0x8000) will always be 0 considering that x will in your case take values <=255 .

I also changed the int arrays which were using way too much space than needed to char arrays.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes now I see where I went wrong, kind of stupid of me.